# How should I persist CredentialPickerResults.Credential for CredentialPickerOptions.PreviousCredential?

Tags: windows-8

I am wanting to use a `CredentialPicker` to prompt for a username and password. When I configure an instance of this class, I can set `CredentialPickerOptions.PreviousCredential` to a value previously obtained by `CredentialPickerResults.Credential`. I believe this causes the dialog to prepopulate the credentials.

However, persisting this value appears to be non-trivial; it's an `IBuffer`, whose members don't appear to contain the relevant credentials. [Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx), page 657, implies that this should be possible:

> An `IBuffer` containing the credential as an opaque byte array. This is what you can
>   save in your own persistent state if needs be and passed back to the picker at a later time; we’ll
>   see how shortly.

Unfortunately, the *we'll see how shortly* appears to only refer to the fact that the value can be passed back *from memory* into `PreviousCredential`; I didn't find any mention of how it's persisted.

Also, I want to persist the credentials using the recommended approach, which I believe is to use `PasswordVault`, however, this appears to only allow me to save the credentials as username and password strings rather than an IBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to ask, and I certainly agree that I could've been more clear in that part of the book. Admittedly, I spent less time on Chapter 14 than I would have liked, but I'll try to remedy that in the next edition. Feedback like yours is extremely valuable in knowing where I need to make improvements, so I appreciate it.

Anyway, writing a buffer to a file is something that was mentioned back in Chapter 8 (and could've been mentioned again here...page 325, though it doesn't mention IBuffer explicitly). It's a straightforward job using the Windows.Storage.FileIO class as shown below (promise!).

First, a clarification. You have two ways to save the entered credentials. If you want to save the plain-text credentials, then absolutely use the Credential Locker. The benefit here is that those credentials can roam automatically with the user if that roaming passwords is enabled in PC Settings (it is by default). Otherwise, you can save the opaque CredentialPickerResults.credential property directly to a file. It's already encrypted and scrambled, so you don't need to use the credential locker in that case.

Now for saving/loading the credential property, which is an IBuffer. For this you use FileIO.writeBufferAsync to save and FileIO.readBufferAsync to reload.

I modified the Credential Picker sample, scenario 3 to demonstrate this. To save the credential property, I added this code at the end of the completed handler for pickAsync:

```
//results.credential will be null if the user cancels
if (results.credential != null) {
    //Having retrieved a credential, write the opaque buffer to a file
    var option = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;

    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync("credbuffer.dat", option).then(function (file) {
        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeBufferAsync(file, results.credential);
    }).done(function () {
        //No results for this operation
        console.log("credbuffer.dat written.");
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Could not create credbuffer.dat file.");
    });
}
```

Then I created a new function to load that credential, if possible. This is called on the Launch button click instead of launchCredPicker:

```
//In the page ready method:
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", readPrevCredentialAndLaunch, false);


//Added
function readPrevCredentialAndLaunch() {
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync("credbuffer.dat").then(function (file) {
        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(file);
    }).done(function (buffer) {
        console.log("Read from credbuffer.dat");
        launchCredPicker(buffer);
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("Could not reopen credbuffer.dat; launching default");
        launchCredPicker(null);
    });
}

//Modified to take a buffer
function launchCredPicker(prevCredBuffer) {    
    try {
        var options = new Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPickerOptions();

        //Other options omitted

        if (prevCredBuffer != null) {
            options.previousCredential = prevCredBuffer;
        }

    //...
```

That's it. I put the modified JS sample on http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/src/CredentialPickerJS_modified.zip.

.Kraig

Author, *[Programming Windows 8 Apps in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook)* (free ebook)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! To me, the ideal would be to save the username and password in the Credential Locker. This way, I think users could view them if they forget them, and as you said, this could enable roaming. However, I couldn't find any way to pass plain text credentials to `CredentialPicker` so it could prepopulate the fields with them. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Good clarification. To persist the credentials between invocations of the credential picker, use the buffer (and to roam it, you'd save it in the roaming folder instead of local). To persist credentials otherwise, use the credential locker. These aren't mutually exclusive--different methods for different purposes. Note that you can invoke the credential picker with alwaysDisplayDialog to false, which I believe allows you to have it decrypt the buffer and return the plain text credentials. In that case you wouldn't need to use the credential locker.

Comment: I just tried to decode the `IBuffer` from within a background task, but I'm receiving an `ArgumentException`. I suspect that I need to do the decoding from the UI thread. I can work around this by saving both the buffer into a file and the credentials into the credential locker. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable. You can't decode the bugger with the credential picker in a background task because it's a UI API and therefore cannot be called from such a task. It's fine to use both methods.